# I can't get my get request to work

Tags: html, angularjs, express, mongoose

i can't get my get request to work, im using angular and im new to it and using it because my project dictates i must use it, im trying to get my entry from my mongodb batabase, im also running an expressjs server ill attach all the code i can please tell me of my mistakes i'm sure there are plenty.

```
//factory
app.factory('whipmeet', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/finalwhipmeet') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return JSON.parse(data); 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
//controller
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'whipmeet', function($scope, whipmeet) {
  whipmeet.success(function(data) {
    $scope.meetinfo = data,
    $scope.meetlikes = 23;
  });
}]);

//index.html(only view)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="WhipMeetApp">
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <h1 id="test1"> teting </h1>
    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container">
         <div class="card" ng-repeat="meet in meets">
    <meet-info info="likes"></meet-info>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!-- modules -->
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<!-- controllers -->
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<!-- services -->
<script src="/javascripts/services/whipmeet.js"></script>
<!-- directives -->
<script src="/javascripts/directives/meetInfo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
//schema im trying to pull
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var MeetSchema = new Schema ({
        name: String,
        location: String,
        car: String,
        date: Date,
        time: Number,
        type: String,
        stock: Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Meet', MeetSchema);
//error i get in console
angular.js:9734 GET http://mongodb//127.0.0.1:27017/finalwhipmeet net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED


​
```

please tell me if i need to post any more files/code for this to be clear, i am really sorry this may be out of format but im a beginner and i'm trying my best to set this up through tutorials and codeacademy, i just need to be able to display my data and how to create a post in the same format.
i greatly appreciate the help of anyone who wants to help, please don't be harsh on a noob.

```
//meets.js route
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Meet = require('../models/Meet.js');

/* GET /meets listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Meet.find(function (err, meets) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(meets);
  });
});

/* POST /meets */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Meet.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* GET /meets/id */
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Meet.findById(req.params.id, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* PUT /meets/:id */
router.put('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Meet.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

/* DELETE /meets/:id */
router.delete('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Meet.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is a wrong approach. Your angular factory should call your express routes, which in turn should talk to mongoDB with native driver or wrapper like Mongoose.

Comment: would you please be so kind of sending me an example of how the code has to be? i also have express requests i'm going to post them now

Comment: @TalhaAwan could you please post a small example of how this should be done? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses callback success and error functions. You can use promises as well.

The angular factory calls express routes, which connects with mongoDB for create, update, delete or get operation and sends the response back to factory. Which passes the result/error to controller.

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'whipmeet', function($scope, whipmeet) {

  //get all
  whipmeet.getWhipmeet(function(data){
      $scope.meetinfo = data;
  },
  function(err){
    console.log(err)
  });

  //get one
  whipmeet.getWhipmeet("id::1234567", function(data){

  },
  function(err){
    console.log(err)
  });


  //create
  whipmeet.createWhipmeet({key: "some value"}, function(data){

  },
  function(err){
    console.log(err)
  });

}]);


app.factory('whipmeet', ['$http', function($http) { 

    return {
        createWhipmeet: function (obj, success, error) {
            $http.post('/meets/', obj, {}).
            then(function (data) {
                success(data)
            }, function (e) {
                error(e);
            });
        },

        getWhipmeets: function (success, error) {
            $http.get('/meets/').
            then(function (data) {
                success(data)
            }, function (e) {
                error(e);
            });
        },

        getWhipmeet: function (id, success, error) {
            $http.get('/meets/'+id).
            then(function (data) {
                success(data)
            }, function (e) {
                error(e);
            });
        }

    }

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you Talha Awan, this does output the data into the /meets route, how would i be able to send this into my scope so i can display the data on on view?

Comment: In your route you're already using `res.json(post);`. This returns the data to factory method which is also passing it to controller. So in `function(data)` on controller you should have the returned data

Comment: thank you, so i should instead of just displaying it, put it in a variable so i can display it partially?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you.  `$scope.meetinfo = data;` assigns the returned data to scope variable. It should show on view wherever you want. You can `console.log(data)` to see what's being returned to verify.

Comment: If you think my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it. Thanks :)